# Is it possible to write the Lovecraftian Sigil of the Gateway in unicode?

Tags: unicode, text-editing, standards

It isn't technically copyrighted and doesn't seem to be subject to trademark, and is kind of a cultural symbol, so for all I know there's a hidden symbol assignment for it somewhere... but the [Sigil of the Gateway](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigil%20of%20the%20gateway&client=firefox-b-1-lm&sxsrf=ALiCzsaiydr-vyXdSDb3BlLqshsQuICXqA:1662933762168&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcgbeB3436AhVVGjQIHVDVBbYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=898&dpr=1) strikes me as an awesome thing to be able to make with unicode modifiers. I would love to put it at the end of some emails and rely on it displaying.

How would one go about doing that? Does anyone know?

I mean, we totally have pentagrams, ⛧⛧⛧, along with just about every other holy symbol and cultural symbol with redundancies.

Comment: I hope someone can come up with a solution. I did try myself some years ago, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: On the other hand, you can convert it to ASCII art: https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/convert-images-to-ascii-art/ . On the third hand... ooops, third claw... oh, never mind that's Niven and Castro, not Hatecraft.

Comment: @Tonny I figured I wouldn't be the only person here who sees the clear and innate value of such a code point. *Ftagn*.